# Xamarin Android Menu item not show dynamically

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on on my app with Xamarin Android and I am having an issue with menu items.
Problem appeared with update of Android libraries - all legacy support is now in AndroidX libraries so I migrated the whole project to it and following happened.

User off my application should be able to login. After login and register buttons hide and logout buttons shows. This works well but I found out it is just because of pop up  login/register dialog, which somehow force the menu to redraw when the dialog closes. Problem is when user logouts, then respectively should login and register button show and logout button hide but only logout hides and other buttons don't show. Only after clicking to something in the menu it redraw itself and button are shown.

It is all shown on screenshots.

[Menu how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weaz9.jpg)

[login popup dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGJAr.jpg)

[after login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMeIi.jpg)

[after logout - buttons not shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep6tv.jpg)

There are how I manipulate buttons:

```
private void SetupGuiAfterSignIn()
    {
        if (!User.IsSignIn())
            return;

        var navheadr = navigationView.GetHeaderView(0).FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.navheader);
        navheadr.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

        var navheaderUsername = navigationView.GetHeaderView(0).FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.navheader_username);
        navheaderUsername.Text = User.GetEmail();

        navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_login).SetVisible(false);
        navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_register).SetVisible(false);
        navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_logout).SetVisible(true);

        navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_find_users).SetVisible(true);

        InvalidateOptionsMenu();

    }

private void SetupGuiAfterLogout()
    {
        if (User.IsSignIn())
            return;

        var navheadr = navigationView.GetHeaderView(0).FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.navheader);
        navheadr.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

        navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_login).SetVisible(true);
        navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_register).SetVisible(true);
        navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_logout).SetVisible(false);

        navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_find_users).SetVisible(false);


        InvalidateOptionsMenu();

    }
```

I also have OnCreateOptionsMenu:

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        navigationView.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.menu); //Navigation Drawer Layout Menu Creation  
        navigationView.InflateHeaderView(Resource.Menu.NavMenuHeader);
        base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the code you provided, i think it caused by the Login, Register, LoginOut is not set in the same group like below.

```
    <menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
android:id="@+id/nav_home"
android:title="Home" />
    <item
android:id="@+id/nav_findusers"
android:visible="false"
android:title="FindUsers" />
    <item
android:id="@+id/nav_import"
android:title="Import" />
    <item
android:id="@+id/nav_FAQ"
android:title="FAQ" />
    <item
android:id="@+id/nav_report"
android:title="ReportBug" />
     
</group>
<item>
    <menu>
        <item
android:id="@+id/nav_Login"
android:title="Login" />
        <item
android:id="@+id/nav_register"
android:title="Register" />
        <item  android:visible="false"
android:id="@+id/nav_LoginOut" 
android:title="LoginOut" />

    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

**Updated:**

**You could use two groups and set the id to show the dividing line.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
android:id="@+id/nav_home"
android:title="Home" />
    <item android:visible="false"
android:id="@+id/nav_findusers"
android:title="FindUsers" />
    <item
  android:id="@+id/nav_import"
android:title="Import" />
    <item
android:id="@+id/nav_FAQ"
android:title="FAQ" />
    <item
android:id="@+id/nav_report"
android:title="ReportBug" />

</group>
<group android:id="@+id/tt" android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
android:id="@+id/nav_Login"
android:title="Login" />
    <item
android:id="@+id/nav_register"
android:title="Register" />
    <item  android:visible="false"
android:id="@+id/nav_LoginOut"
android:title="LoginOut" />
</group>
</menu>
```

**Menu how it looks:**

[image]

After login:

[image]

After logout:

[image]

The code when the item clicked:

```
  void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView)
    {
        navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
        {

            switch (e.MenuItem.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.nav_home:
                    {
                        //drawerLayout.OpenDrawer(Resource.Layout.Home);
                        //var home = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity_Home));
                        //StartActivity(home);
                        //navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_LoginOut).SetVisible(true);
                        break;
                    }

                case Resource.Id.nav_Login:
                    {
                        navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_LoginOut).SetVisible(true);
                        navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_findusers).SetVisible(true);
                        navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_Login).SetVisible(false);
                        navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_register).SetVisible(false);

                        
                        break;
                    }

                case Resource.Id.nav_LoginOut:
                    {
                        navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_Login).SetVisible(true);
                        navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_register).SetVisible(true);
                        navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_LoginOut).SetVisible(false);

                        navigationView.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.nav_findusers).SetVisible(false);
                        break;
                    }

                default:
                    break;

                    //TODO check the ID and start your activity or switch the fragments
            }

            //e.MenuItem.SetChecked(true);
            //drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
        };
    }
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot for the fast response, it actually works, but stil it is kinda workaround. Do you  know why is this happening or if it is deprecated or something like that? ...it makes me curious because it happened after migration on newer android libraries.

Comment: I guess this layout do not update correctly when using nested menu. You could use the workaround instead.

Comment: Yes, I got it, but there should be a proper explanation why it does not work. I appreciate this solution because i was stuck with it for a while but this makes it looking little bit different. So I would like to solve it in the "proper" way, make it works how it is designed yet.
Do you have some docs link for example where it is described?

Comment: I need more time to confirm and would feedback ASAP.

Comment: @renegato I use two groups and set the id to show the ividing line. Please check my update.

Comment: I split it into two groups, gave both groups different IDs. Dividing line is showing well but the problem remains. After logging out, those menu items that should apper, don't appear. I also tired to call `MenuCompat.SetGroupDividerEnabled(menu, true);` in `OnCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: Update: I tried also more things... Important is to have also in the second group property: `android:checkableBehavior="single"` . Now it works fine. Thanks @Wendy Zang - MSFT for your effort.